# Where can I find data set of tweets of users?

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, nlp, social-media

I am doing a project "Emotional prediction of user based on tweets", using data mining techniques. For this purpose, I need a data set of tweets of users.
Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's against [Twitter's policy](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/terms/agreement-and-policy#6.Update_Be_a_Good_Partner_to_Twitter) to provide datasets of more than user and tweet IDs.

However, as lots of people are tweeting every day, you can construct your own dataset using the twitter api: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public

There are many guides on how to mine tweets, for example: https://marcobonzanini.com/2015/03/02/mining-twitter-data-with-python-part-1/